# Semantic-ui main menu CSS hover and focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I have am problem with the styling of my navbar with semantic-ui. I like to change the color and background-color on hover and change the focus. But everything I do it just does not change the hover. I was only able to do it with jQuery, but that should not be the solution for this problem.

This is the code I use for that part:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main.menu').visibility({
      type: 'fixed'
    });
  })
;
```

```css
a.nav.item:hover {
  background: #1B1C1D;
  color: #17AA1C;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui borderless inverted stackable main menu">
    <div class="ui text container">
      <div href="#" class="header item">
        <i class="code icon" id="myicon"></i>
        Name
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav item">Me</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav item">Current Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav item">Blog</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav item">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style you want to override is chained with the .inverted class.

This will work for example.

```
.ui.inverted.menu .dropdown.item:hover,
.ui.inverted.menu .link.item:hover,
.ui.inverted.menu a.item:hover,
.ui.link.inverted.menu .item:hover {
  background: #1B1C1D;
  color: #17AA1C;
}
```

jsbin https://output.jsbin.com/yijowusiqe